# onClick not triggering when button is in LinearLayout on Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-button

So I'm trying to make something similar to how snapchat does the options menu where you slide down and you can still see the camera in the background. I won't post all the code, but I've debugged what it is that's causing a problem. I'm a noob to android dev, but I've done some java programming before.

This is my xml

```
<me.dontenvy.videotest.MainMenu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:id="@+id/main_menu">

<!-- this is for the camera -->
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/camera_container">

    <TextureView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/texture"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>

<!-- this is for the overlay menu -->
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/slide_menu"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:background="@drawable/transparent_background">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/clear_background"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/slide_button"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="@dimen/circle_nav_button_diameter"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/circle_nav_button_diameter"
            android:background="@drawable/circle_button"
            android:backgroundTint="#050"
            android:id="@+id/take_image_nav_button"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
</me.dontenvy.videotest.MainMenu>
```

I add the onClick listener within my MainMenu.java class which extends RelativeLayout. Here is a gist with the rest of the code https://gist.github.com/colmex/1bd19dd2cfc400b2f870

The issue is that when the @id/take_image_nav_button is in the LinearLayout, the onClick action doesn't work, when I take it out of it's LinearLayout, the onClick action does work. It feels like the LinearLayout is somehow blocking the click. I've tried a lot of things I've found on stackoverflow and other googling, but nothing seems to fix it.

Comment: Can you add the relevant part of your main code?

Comment: I added it to a gist https://gist.github.com/colmex/1bd19dd2cfc400b2f870

Answer (score 0):

On the LinearLayout parent to the button you have set `android:clickable="false"`, but this makes everything inside it unclickable too. To fix it, change `false` to `true`

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:clickable="true"> // Change here to true, like this
```

Or simply remove this attribute.

Comment: just tried that and it didn't work also tried taking it out and it didn't work. Updated posting

Comment: @LuisFHernandez alright, sorry. If you put it right above this linear layout it becomes clickable, right? Because there's another `android:clickable="false"` on the first layout, but if the button was working inside it before i'm probably wrong about removing this atribute.

Comment: I took out the other `android:clickable="false"` I didn't notice that was there. Basically if I put the `@id/take_image_nav_button` out of it's parent LinearLayout and have it in just the `@id/slide_menu` RelativeLayout, it works, I can click it. But when it's inside the LinearLayout that's inside the `@id/slide_menu` RelativeLayout it doesn't work, I can't click it.